# DataGridView adding blank rows to DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have a DataGridView which is data binded to a DataTable.
UserAddRows is enabled, as i want to be able to add rows manualy.
Problem is, if a user clicks on the blank row at the bottom, and then leaves it and enters another row, a blank row is still added to the DataTable.

How can I change this behaviour, so if I leave a DataGridView row with all fields blank or DBNull, it wouldn't be added to the DataTable?

Comment: Can't you tried to analyze if the row is blank you don't add it to the database?

Comment: Would love to, but i couldn't find a way to do that.. whatever event I try to listen to to see if the line is blank, happens before the row is added to the datatable... And if there is a way to cancel the event that adds it to the DT, that would be even better.

Comment: Or you delete the blank row from the database.

Comment: Wait, you mean it is adding a blank row to the application-side DataTable, right? It is NOT adding a row to the database table?

In other words, it's showing up as an empty row in the datagridview and you can keep creating more empty rows below it, which would be a user interface issue, not a data issue. Am I correct?

Comment: Umm... I'm parsing an xml to a DataTable, which is then used as a datasource to a DataGridView. what I described adds a new row to the DataTable, but it doesn't show in the DataGridView. In the grid there is still only 1 blank row.